# Regex that does not match if consecutive N number of words are upper case

Tags: python, regex

I'd appreciate some help constructing a regex that matches the following, but not the last example.

My goal is to match words that come after Source, but these words should be organization names.  99% of these organization names are not all upper case. I'd like to avoid matching tags that simply have the word SOURCE in them, and these are often n-length upper case words.

Organization names are not all upper-case. They can take the form of anything, not just 'Foundation' etc.

Match

```
SOURCE Skoll Foundation SUBJECT: --> 'Skoll Foundation'

SOURCE: Skoll Foundation; ABC Found; Institute of Humane INDUSTRY: --> ['Skoll Foundation', 'ABC Found', 'Institute of Humane']
SOURCE SKOLL Foundation --> ['SKOLL Foundation']
```

Do not match these:

```
OPEN SOURCE SOFTWARE  (89%)
SOURCE SOFTWARE ENTERPRISE
```

My attempt, but I realize this just matches 'SOURCE' in the example up top.

```
pat = 'SOURCE:?\s+(?![A-Z\s]{2,20})?'
```

Comment: Provide some clarity on why it should match first list but should not match second one.

Comment: what is difference between 3rd and 5th line? How to distinguish between them?

Comment: Why it shouldn't match `OPEN SOURCE SOFTWARE` but should match `SOURCE SKOLL Foundation`?

Comment: @anubhava I'm only trying to match organization names.

Comment: first decide what you want to ask? you have edited your sample 3 times.

Comment: @Braj sorry. I was trying to give a toy example to make it easy on the eyes, but I added constants that weren't there. Next time I'll just copy/paste chunks of my actual data.

Comment: @user3314418: How is `SOFTWARE` not an organization name but `SKOLL` is?

Comment: Is SUBJECT or INDUSTRY static?

Comment: @anubhava 99% of organization names are not all caps.

Comment: @Braj What do you mean by static? Sometimes it's INDUSTRY:, sometimes it's SUBJECT:, or other words like LANGUAGE. The textual data is variable. However the words are typically uppercase and have semicolons after them.

Comment: Would `SOURCE Skoll Foundation; ABC FOUND` match or not?  How does one decide which words get dropped from the result?  (Note that "typically" and "99%" doesn't cut it, unless you are OK with the atypical cases being handled wrongly.)

Comment: ABC FOUND doesn't match. but Skoll Foundation does.

Comment: This question seems too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe following regex should work for you:

```
\bSOURCE\b:?(?!( +[A-Z]+){2}\b)((?: +\w+){2,})
```

#### [Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uB9uY3/4)

Basically this regex just discards any text after literal text `SOURCE` if that text contains 2 consecutive all capital words.

Comment: this is really close! but it appears to match when I put in the full text that has \s+ (89%). See here: http://regex101.com/r/uB9uY3/1

Comment: Sorry, here's the correct link where I include that text http://regex101.com/r/uB9uY3/2

Comment: you are amazing! thanks. one final thing: could you give me a bit of exlanation for how this regex pattern works? I can't  decode the pattern explanation in the demo.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. Core of this regex is negative lookahead `(?!( +[A-Z]+){2}\b)`. This negative lookahead means don't match if there are 2 consecutive all uppercase words (separated by spaces) after literal `SOURCE`.

Comment: Thanks @zx81, this was little tricky as question was edited several times to clarify the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you have provided, a pattern that says that there is at least 1 lower-case letter after `SOURCE` somewhere would do the trick.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should match the top three you've shown:

```
(SOURCE.*[S][Kk][Oo].+\s*)
```

code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(SOURCE.*[S][Kk][Oo].+\s*)', re.MULTILINE)

re.findall(p, str)
```

example:

http://regex101.com/r/uR5uW3/5

Comment: This adds `Skol` at the end of every match

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about how this regex works? Do you put [S] and [F] to just give the option of starting with those letters?

Comment: In your question it appears there is `Foundation` on each line; am I missing something?

Comment: I just updated my question. Sorry, I was trying to give a toy example, but I created a constant that wasn't there.

Comment: For the explanation check out: http://regex101.com/r/uR5uW3/4 (it describes what each item in the pattern does).

Comment: use `re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE` for ignore case.

Comment: @Braj, If I ignore case, it won't match correctly, as I use the uppercase `S` to match against.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the subject of your post the below would print Failed if it found more than n consecutive upper case words. I have not used regex but this should work.

```
s = "SOURCE SKOLL foundation"
splitData = s.split(" ")
n = 1 # Max consecutive upper case words that are acceptable
i = 0
for eachWord in splitData:
    i += eachWord.isupper()
    if i > n:
        print("Failed")
        break
    if not eachWord.isupper():
        i = 0
```